# iis 7.5 application pool problems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have a very simple website, maybe 10 users on it at same time. big maybe. more like 1 or 2.  If a user is on website, sometimes it will time out or not hit my database for an extremely simple query.  I have to recycle the application pool and then everything is fine for an hour then the problem happens again.

Prior to this, all I can remember doing was, trying to make the website not timeout on a user after 20 minutes, I tried to increase it to 2 hours.  since then I have changed everything back to 20 minutes, but this is still happening.

also, I have this on my .vb page in the page load, not sure if this effects anything?

```
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(False)
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    '  1500 seconds is 25 minutes
    Response.Expires = -1500
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
```

Can anyone help me please, its a small website but its extremely important for our company. thanks,

Comment: You seem to be mixing "timeout" (server timeout) and "user session" (20 min)? Leaky app/db conn for former is likely. Check your Event logs...

Comment: I will check that. should I remove this line of code above? I had added it a long time ago to make sure users were getting the latest page and not a cached page.  but I use this same code in another website and they aren't getting these problems. should I remove all 7 lines or just a few of them, which ones?

Comment: i just did a test & i clicked submit & it sometimes takes 2-3 seconds to complete, but before it completed i hit submit again like users sometimes do & i did that a couple of times. after that, the website was hosed for me & others, it kept not connecting to the DB until i recycled the app in IIS.  ??

Comment: i checked the event logs and i don't see anything peculiar.

Comment: i added code to disable all buttons on screen when one input button is clicked.  it seems that users are double or triple clicking a button, & so the server sends multiple requests to IIS and it gets all confused & then times out, never working until i recycle application pool on IIS.  is there a setting is iis app pool i can change to help with this problem?

Comment: Then the issue is in code/application (leaky, db connections, etc).  Application Pool recycling/settings is **not** where you should be looking.